# How do I transform a number into a char* for syscall write in x86 64 Assembly GAS

Tags: assembly, int, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I'm having trouble with changing the value in %rax, which is 1 into a char* for it to be printed in a syscall write in x86 64 Assembly GAS. It produces a segmentation fault. No stdlib.

```
# Write Implementation
mov %rax,rsi    #Number to print
mov     $1, %rax                #Write
mov     $1, %rdi                #File Handle 1
mov     $4, %rdx
syscall
```

Comment: `rsi` is supposed to point to the buffer to print.  A pointer of `1` is not going to be a valid buffer.  You need to have some memory (perhaps on the stack?) that you write the character to.  Also, there is a difference between `rax` containing the value `1`, and it containing the ascii value for `1` (aka 49).  If you want to show a 1 on the screen, you want the ascii value.

Comment: My answer on the linked duplicate has a nice and commented implementation of the function you're trying to write.  (Using a tmp buffer on the stack).

Comment: Also, the segfault you're getting is after `sys_write` returns and you fall off the end of the function.  Passing a bogus pointer to `sys_write` will make it return `-EFAULT`.  i.e. you have a separate segfault-causing bug, passing the integer as a pointer doesn't explain that.